Как создать SFTP пользователя с доступом к bash? Ubuntu 22 04
вы - моя последняя надежда, убил на эту задачу уже около недели.
Мне необходимо создать два пользователя, оба SFTP.
user1 должен иметь доступ к /var/www и абсолютно ко всему, что есть в директории, полные права. (С этим у меня, вроде бы, более менее удалось, но иногда слетают права, как с этим можно бороться?)
user2 должен иметь доступ к /var/www/site/dev/project, тоже SFTP, но с доступом к bash, чтобы мог деплоить back-end часть на Java
Они оба должны работать в одной директории, потому что user1 тоже имеет доступ к той же директории, что и user2. root тоже может редактировать эти файлы, но чтобы права не слетали у пользователей.
Я изрыл все, начиная от YT с индусами, заканчивая полное насилие GPT, никак не могу найти рабочее решение, постоянно все ломается.
Прошу вас о помощи.. Заранее благодарю!

Я бы сделал одну общую группу. Если там веб-сервер работает, можно использовать его группу, ведь веб-сервер тоже должен иметь доступ. Допустим, это группа httpd. Назначает первичную группу пользователям sudo usermod -g httpd user1 (для второго аналогично). Также должны быть договоренности, чтобы пользователи выкладывали файлы в режиме чтения/записи для группы. Далее назначить дефолтные права на файл через umask, должно быть "0002" - в конфиге sshd.

Делаете докер-контейнер, к которому примонтирована эта папка и в котором работает ftp под нужным uid, даете параметры доступа пользователям. Для "деплоить back-end часть на Java" поступаете аналогично, но даете параметры доступа только второму пользователю.

SELinux вам в помощь (и расширенные аттрибуты), чтобы не слетали права доступа.
